# Do android animations use a lot more CPU power?

Tags: android, android-animation, cpu-usage, battery

I am using `Animations` in my application while

1. switching among `Activities`
2. populating `ListView`.

now I am wondering if it uses a lot more `CPU power` which uses more `Battery`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, any calculation by the cpu uses power, and I have to believe that you have to do a lot more calculation to animate those items, so I would say yes, it would affect the battery life.

I can't imagine it would be drastic though... people use Live Wallpapers, and some searching on the nets shows that those (depending on the device) can use an extra 2-4% power, and that's for something that runs 100% of the time when visible, as opposed to list creation which happens in a finite amount of time.

Upshot:  I wouldn't worry about it.

Answer (score 1):

Sure it does, but i don't believe is significant at all. Those are really simple operations when compared to whole process of launching an activity or loading lists. you can test it if you like by using traceview.

[TraceView Sample](http://tech.any.do/android-performance-optimization/)